# Im getting this error: “ braced block of statements is an unused closure, expected expression and expression resolves to an unused function"

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

This is my first time doing a kinda simple project and these errors shows up.
I've been trying for the past 2-3 hours to get this work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YHbT.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typed it a bit wrong, try this instead:

```
if let uid = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid") {

}
```

You either need to assign the `if let` to a `variable name` or use `_`.